# AMD Radeon HD 3000 Series (I installed but where is aticonfig)

Tags: 13.04, drivers, ati, radeon, catalyst

I had Dell studio 1536 laptop with windows vista defaults already installed.
recently I decided to shift from Microsoft windows to ubuntu.

I installed Ubuntu gnome 3. After installation It's look like that everything is ok.
but I found that ubuntu perform much more slowly than Vista!!!

I discovered that ubuntu uses an alternative driver for my Graphic card.
Take a look to this:

[image]

Then i decided to download & install proper ATI (AMD) driver, from [here](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/legacy/Pages/legacy-radeon_linux.aspx).

My on-board graphic card is: ATI radeon HD 3200

**THE QUESTION: IS IT IMPORTANT TO REMOVE PREVIOUS AMD DRIVER WHICH INSTALLED BY DEFAULT?**

**AND THEN WHAT IS ATICONFIG ? SAVE X WINDOW CONFIGURATION FILE? 
TAKE A LOOK TO THIS SCREEN SHOT:**

[image]

any suggestion would become helpful

Answer (score 1):

Check [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI). It gives the most comprehensive explanation on ways to install ATI Drivers. The link will answer most of your questions. I presume that you want to install the drivers manually, you might want to read section 3 in the link.

`aticonfig --initial` configures X to use ATI drivers provided they are installed properly. Make sure you run this command as soon as your drivers are installed completely and before rebooting.

Comment: the problem is that terminal can not find this command. how can i execute it ?

Comment: According to the images you have posted, you have not installed the drivers but merely generated packages for some linux distro. Hence, you will not be able to run `aticonfig --initial`. Install the driver according to one of the methods given in the link I posted earlier and you will be able to run that command.